# How to set item height in custom listView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I implemented a custom listView as seen here:
http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/ but I can't get a correct height for my items in the list. Both header and section layout are way too large (height).

[image: problem item height]

Here is my xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/profileLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    >


    <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_profilePicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_profileName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_logout"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sectionLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_sectionName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_headerName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="#DADADC" ></View>


</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestion ?

[EDIT] Here is my customDrawerAdapter getview code:

```
    public class CustomDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItem> {

private final JSONObject userProfile;
Context context;
List<DrawerItem> drawerItemList;
int layoutResID;

public CustomDrawerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,
                           List<DrawerItem> listItems, JSONObject userProfile) {
    super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
    this.context = context;
    this.drawerItemList = listItems;
    this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;
    this.userProfile = userProfile;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DrawerItemHolder drawerHolder;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        drawerHolder = new DrawerItemHolder();

        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
        drawerHolder.profileName = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.drawer_profileName);
        drawerHolder.profilePicture = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_profilePicture);
        drawerHolder.sectionName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_sectionName);
        drawerHolder.headerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_headerName);

        drawerHolder.buttonLogout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_logout);
        drawerHolder.buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        drawerHolder.profileLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.profileLayout);
        drawerHolder.sectionLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sectionLayout);
        drawerHolder.headerLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.headerLayout);

        view.setTag(drawerHolder);

    } else {
        drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    DrawerItem dItem = this.drawerItemList.get(position);

    if (dItem.isHeader()) {
        drawerHolder.profileLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
        drawerHolder.sectionLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
        drawerHolder.headerLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        drawerHolder.headerName.setText(dItem.getHeaderName());

    } else if (dItem.getProfilePicture() == 0){
        drawerHolder.profileLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
        drawerHolder.sectionLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        drawerHolder.headerLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
        drawerHolder.sectionName.setText(dItem.getSectionName());
    } else {

        drawerHolder.profileLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        drawerHolder.sectionLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
        drawerHolder.headerLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
        try {
            if (userProfile.getString("facebookId") != null) {
                String facebookId = userProfile.get("facebookId")
                        .toString();
                drawerHolder.profilePicture.setProfileId(facebookId);
            } else {
                // Show the default, blank user profile picture
                drawerHolder.profilePicture.setProfileId(null);
            }
            if (userProfile.getString("name") != null) {
                drawerHolder.profileName.setText(userProfile.getString("name"));
            } else {
                drawerHolder.profileName.setText("");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(CarpoolMeApp.TAG,
                    "Error parsing saved user data.");
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the height manually for both the headerName and the sectionName Textviews

```
    android:layout_height="2dp"
```

like you did with the View in your headerLayout

Comment: I'm sure that wrap-content is working fine, it will only collapse it's bounds as far as the largest element it's trying to wrap. Changing the size of the text inside of your TextView will ultimately control the layout's size too:         android:textSize="14sp"

Comment: Whenever I change the layout_height, the textview height is reducing but not the item of the listview.

Comment: You should keep all of your layouts height to wrap_content. You need to adjust the size of the content in your TextViews. Your origninal complaint was that your text is too large, then you should remove the textAppearanceLarge attribute, and manage your text sizes manually with          android:textSize="14sp"

Comment: I added a picture of my problem. That's not the text which bother me but the container of the text.

Comment: In the image above, "Find" "Discover" and "Search" correspond to which TextView/Button elements?

Comment: Find is the headerLayout and Discover/Search is the sectionLayout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58909/discussion-between-will-thomson-and-arnaudtoutain).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify layouts gravities, it is most possible reason of issue (too much height).
Also you can use LinearLayout as root layout instead of RelativeLayout.
If the exact height needed, specify it in the **layout_height** parameter.